# Using a .SQL file as a string input in AWS CloudFormation YAML file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm brand new to CloudFormation, so I thought I'd try asking here about something I'm trying to do.

So our team is attempting to use CloudFormation to create a dataset in AWS QuickSight. The YAML file has a portion that looks like this:

```
  Columns: 
    - InputColumn
  DataSourceArn: String
  Name: String
  SqlQuery: String
```

It's that SqlQuery field in particular that's really important. I could just copy/paste the SQL query in there, but it's several hundred lines long and that would be unsightly. So my question is if there's a good way to reference a .SQL file (ex: dataset_query.sql) either locally or stored somewhere else and use the contents of that field to fill in that string field. It'd be nice if  it handles files with line breaks in them, too!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use a file as an input like you're describing with just Cloudformation. One thing you could use is the [Cloud Development Kit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html), this would give you a lot more options to store your SQL file and launch your stack from there.